# How to process each of the allShortestPaths in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have a Neo4j graph with several relationships, each of them having property y (number). I want to find all shortest paths between node with name 'x' and all other nodes and then, for each of these paths, calculate sum of the path edges properties and return the minimum of these sums.

```
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((m)-[r*]-(n)) 
WHERE m.name = 'x' AND n.name <> 'x'
RETURN n.name, //min(sum(edge.y for y in path) for path in paths) -- something like this
```

So, is there some way to process each of the found paths independently and apply some function to their edges?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course. The `allShortestPaths` query returns a `List` of paths that you can unwind, then for each of them you can [`reduce`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) the properties of the relationships :

```
MATCH paths = allShortestPaths((m)-[r*]-(n)) 
WHERE m.name = 'x' AND n.name <> 'x'
UNWIND paths AS path
WITH n.name AS name, 
reduce(total = 0, rel IN relationships(path) | total + rel.y) AS total
RETURN name, min(total)
```